# Efficient query on a sorted csv

Tags: python, csv, search

I have a .csv with several million rows. The first column is the id of each entry, and each id only occurs one time. The first column is sorted. Intuitively I'd say that it might be pretty easy to query this file efficiently using a divide and conquer algorithm. However, I couldn't find anything related to this.

Sample .csv file:

```
+----+------------------+-----+
| id | name             | age |
+----+------------------+-----+
| 1  | John Cleese      | 34  |
+----+------------------+-----+
| 3  | Mary Poppins     | 35  |
+----+------------------+-----+
| .. | ...              | ..  |
+----+------------------+-----+
| 87 | Barry Zuckerkorn | 45  |
+----+------------------+-----+
```

I don't want to load the file in memory (too big), and I prefer to not use databases. I know I can just import this file in sqlite, but then I have multiple copies of this data, and I'd prefer to avoid that for multiple reasons.

Is there a good package I'm overlooking? Or is it something that I'd have to write myself?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: Pandas has a very easy to use `read_csv` function. But I think it loads the entire file.

Comment: if all the rows have constant length, then you could easily jump to the keys using seek and a binary search. However, if the keys don't have a known position in the stream, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Does the sample file really have all these dashes and plus signs?? `+----+------------------+-----+`

Comment: @Praind: I have not downvoted, but OP has chosen a poor solution (several million rows in a text file), says that he does not want to use the common way (database) but does not really explain why. And the question is close to *what is the package to use*...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Yes you got a point...

Comment: The file is being shared by multiple persons with different backgrounds and I prefer to keep only a single copy of this data. That's why I'd prefer to keep it in .csv. Since the data is indexed anyways, I was thinking about a more efficient query than just looping over the file.

Comment: @Joost *shared by multiple persons with different backgrounds*. This is the target for a database and one or more interface applications over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my understanding is that you want some of the functionnalities of a light database, but are constrained to use a csv text file to hold the data. IMHO, this is probably a questionable design: past several hundred of rows, I would only see a csv file an an intermediate or exchange format.

As it is a very uncommon design, it is unlikely that a package for it already exists - for my part I know none. So I would imagine 2 possible ways: scan the file once and build an index id->row_position, and then use that index for your queries. Depending on the actual length of you rows, you could index only every n-th row to change speed for memory. But it costs an index file

An alternative way would be a direct divide and conquer algo: use stat/fstat to get the file size, and search for the next end of line starting at the middle of the file. You immediately get an id after it. If the id you want is that one, fine you have won, if it is greater, just recurse in the upper part, if lesser, recurse in the lower part. But because of the necessity to search for end of lines, be prepared to corner case like never finding the end of line in the expected range, or find it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is exactly the question I was trying to ask. Those were also the solutions I had in mind, basically dump `{id: position}` entries into a pickle, or the divide and conquer method. I was trying to search for something along those lines, but couldn't find anything. I'll see what I'll use in the end.

Comment: Beware that the csv format allow for newlines characters within rows. Seems not to be the case for your current file but...

Comment: I've implemented it, and it finds all possible ids which is nice :). @brunodesthuilliers thanks for the heads up, but I don't have newlines in my csv file. That would have made my life *a lot* harder.

Answer (score 0):

After Serges answer I decided to write my own implementation, here it is. It doesn't allow newlines and doesn't deal with a lot of details regarding the .csv format. It assumes that the .csv is sorted on the first column, and that the first column are integer values.

```
import os

def query_sorted_csv(fname, id):
    filesize = os.path.getsize(fname)

    with open(fname) as fin:
        row = look_for_id_at_location(fin, 0, filesize, id)
        if not row:
            raise Exception('id not found!')

    return row

def look_for_id_at_location(fin, location_lower, location_upper, id, sep=',', id_column=0):
    location = int((location_upper + location_lower) / 2)
    if location_upper - location_lower < 2:
        return False
    fin.seek(location)
    next(fin)
    try:
        full_line = next(fin)
    except StopIteration:
        return False

    id_at_location = int(full_line.split(sep)[id_column])
    if id_at_location == id:
        return full_line

    if id_at_location > id:
        return look_for_id_at_location(fin, location_lower, location, id)

    else:
        return look_for_id_at_location(fin, location, location_upper, id)

row = query_sorted_csv('data.csv', 505)
```

You can look up about 4000 ids per second in a 2 million row 250MB .csv file. In comparison, you can look up 3 ids per second whilst looping over the entire file line by line.